# Debugging my R code that is not functioning correctly

Tags: r

I am trying to fix my code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but the code is supposed to retrieve all values from vector `x` that are:

- larger than two standard deviations from the average

or

- smaller than two standard deviations from the average.

```
set.seed(2)
x = rnorm(10000)
average = mean(x)
upper_bound = average + sd(average)
lower_bound = average - sd(average)
boolean_vector = x < lower_bound | x > upper_bound
y = x[boolean_vector]
```

Comment: Your definitions of the bounds should be `sd(x)` instead of `sd(average)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not take the standard deviation of an integer so instead of

```
upper_bound = average + sd(average)
lower_bound = average - sd(average)
```

you would do

```
upper_bound = average + sd(x)
lower_bound = average - sd(x)
```

plus you want to be 2 standard deviations away so it would be

```
upper_bound = average + 2*sd(x)
lower_bound = average - 2*sd(x)
```